# .NET 5 API add Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers - with Ionic 5.5

Tags: asp.net-core, ionic-framework, cors

Can you please assist, I have a .NET 5 Web API and Ionic 5.5 app. I have deployed the API and the Ionic app to Azure Web Services. The API is serving the Ionic app, so they are on the same domain - I can say same origin because the scheme, and domain are the same.

The issue is that, the Ionic app is failing to call the API because it seems like CORS is blocking it.
In my API, I have allowed any origin, any header and credentials but it's still not working. I have attached my Startup.cs file for the .NET 5 API.

**Startup.cs** code

```
using AutoMapper;
using EventManager.Business.Repositories;
using EventManager.Database;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace EventManager.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                               .AllowAnyHeader()
                               .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
                //options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            });

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddApiVersioning(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(2, 1);
                x.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                x.ReportApiVersions = true;

                // Supporting multiple versioning scheme
                x.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
            });

            services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
            {
                options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
                options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = false;
            });

            var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
            {
                mc.AddProfile(new Business.MappingProfile());
            });

            var mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();

            services.AddSingleton(mapper);

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "Event Manager API Documentation",
                    Version = "v1",
                    Contact = new OpenApiContact
                    {
                        Email = "eric@xxxxx.com",
                        Name = "Eric Smith",
                        Url = new Uri("https://www.xxxxx.org/")
                    },
                    Description = @"Used for as a self-service for event attendees. 
                                To capture attendee details and print out attendee badges",
                    License = new OpenApiLicense
                    {
                        Name = "Use under LICX",
                        Url = new Uri("https://www.xxxxx.org/api/license"),
                    }
                });

                //Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MSSqlConnection"),
            b => b.MigrationsAssembly("EventManager.Database")));

            services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.AddScoped<EventRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<AttendeeRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<DesignationRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<EntryQuestionRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<EntryQuestionSectionRepository>();

            //Sart: To serve angular app
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => { configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp"; });
            //End: To serve angular app
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "EventManager.Api v1"));
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(builder =>
            {
                builder
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
            });

            app.UseAuthorization();

            //Start: To serve angular app
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            //End: To serve angular app

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            //Start: To serve angular app
            app.UseSpa(spa => { spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp"; });
            //End: To serve angular app
        }
    }
}
```

**My API call from the Ionic app**

```
headers = new HttpHeaders({
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + "XXXXXXX",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });

//environment.api = 'https://myazureappname.azurewebsites.net/api/'

get(cellNumber?: string): Observable<AttendeeGetModel[]> {
    return this._http.get<AttendeeGetModel[]>(`${environment.api}v1/attendees?cellNumber=${cellNumber}`, { headers: this.headers });
  }

**Error message from Firefox browser attached**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it's the same domain, then there should be no options request. What are the exact and full URLs from a) browser location and b) request (from network tab > request > details)?

Comment: What happens if you call the URL in postman? (Background: If there are exceptions your cors request will fail and while your browser tells you "CORS" it's not really CORS related but simply a wrong url / exception / ...)

Comment: @ChristophLütjen the request is working fine in Postman. It's returning the expected data. I have edited the question with Postman results.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I have also added another screenshot with the response from Chrome browser. The error in the Network -> Status says "(failed) net:: ERR_NAME_NOT RESOLVED"

Comment: The error ERR_NAME_NOT RESOLVED typically means: Chrome cannot resolve the domain name which in most cases menas you're using the wrong domain name or have a typo. In your case it looks like the tld. Postman = ".net", Your app = ".com"?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I cannot believe that I made that mistake. You are absolutely right. My app is using a .com instead of a .net. Thank you so much for paying attention to the URLs. I would like to make your comment an answer to my problem please. I really appreciate this. You have no idea how much time I have spent trying to figure out this issue. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

The error ERR_NAME_NOT RESOLVED typically means: Chrome cannot resolve the domain name which in most cases means you're using the wrong domain name or have a typo.
In your case it looks like your're using the wrong top level domain in your app. Postman = ".net", Your app = ".com".